# Image from database not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6.2

I have a problem with my project; the problem is the uploaded image to the database is not found and is not displaying on the page.

[Galleries upload error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9auxU.jpg)

And these are the scripts.

**gallery.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($galleryImages as $galleryImage)
    <div class="gallery-card">
        <a href="detailed-gallery.html">
            <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $galleryImage->image_path) }}">
        </a>
        <p>{{ $galleryImage->title }}</p>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**AppController.php**

```
public function gallery()
{
    $setting = \App\Setting::first();
    $galleryImages = Gallery::all();

    return view('gallery', compact('setting', 'galleryImages'));
}
```

**GalleryController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'image_path' => 'required|image',
    ]);

    Gallery::create(array_merge($data, ['image_path' => $data['image_path']->store('uploads/attachments', 'public')]));

    return redirect()->route('galleries.index');
}
```

There are no errors on my friend's laptop, and they don't show on the page; what is it that the different OS affects? My friend is using Windows, and I'm using Ubuntu Linux; what's the solution?

Comment: Did you link your storage folder? `php artisan storage:link` [The Public Disk](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Comment: Yes, I'm not yet modified or change the script or other after I get from my friend @brombeer